# strange issue with NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I have an array in my app delegate.In some other class I am adding few dictionaries in this app delegate array.

There only I set this appdelegate array for a key in NSUserDefaults.Later on when I check NSUserDefaults value for key for which I saved the appdelegate array, always shows **zero** object.

I am using

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:app.testArray forKey:@"theKey"];
```

Comment: Did u synchronize the user defaults?

Comment: please add a comment before downvoting anything, so that we can correct ourself

Comment: @Swastik : Dont accept if you dont want to. Its up to you. Its for your good not mine. If none of your answers help you then you can set a bounty to get an answer to that. Its just a suggestion. I am not imposing anything on you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code. I am very sure that it will work for you.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 

[defaults setObject:yourArray forKey:@"init_val"]; 

[defaults synchronize];
```

For Retrieving Data You Should Use The Following Code :

```
NSMutableArray *newArray=[[[NSUserDefaults alloc] objectForKey:@"init_val"] mutableCopy];
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Also can you please post more of your code? So that we can figure out where exactly the problem is.

Comment: NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
 
 [defaults setObject:appDelegate.arr forKey:@"init_val"]; 
 
 [defaults synchronize];
 
 NSMutableArray *newArray=[[[NSUserDefaults alloc] objectForKey:@"init_val"] mutableCopy];

Comment: my newArray shows zero objects, whereas my appDelegate.arr has moreobjects

Comment: Also where? on app delegate do you give this UserDefaults? or in some other view? If you are giving its value in some other view, do you allocate the appdelegate object properly?

Comment: You can give some random value and check the nsuserdefaults. I suspect you are trying to save a null value i.e both the arrays are different.

Comment: i have initialized the appdelegate object

Comment: look i tired both the ways, if i create any temporary NSArray , ur code works

Comment: @fluchtpunkt: Also one more thing(I am not arguing) [NSUserDefaults alloc] does work

Comment: @Fluchtpunkt: You being an old & reputed member of StackOverflow, atleast these words (like WTF) are not expected out of you here. You should read **Be Nice** section of this link: http://stackoverflow.com/faq Hope you understand. Nothing personal but my point is just that we are here to help each other out, not fight and abuse.

Comment: That this code works is just coincidence. You should never use an object without initing it first (or making use of the implicit init called by `standardUserDefaults`). Not only that your code leaks an instance of NSUserDefaults but it teaches people bad practice that only works in this particular case. And you are relying on the internals of NSUserDefaults. What happens if the developers of NSUserDefaults decide that they put an extra abstraction layer inside the class that is created in `init`? Exactly, your code will crash. --- Nice enough? I hope so.

Comment: fluchtpunkt: ok thanks for the information. I will definitely keep this in mind while using NSUserDefaults next time. Yeah it is definitely very nice. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for retrieving data

```
NSMutableArray *newArray=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"init_val"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use object for key instead of valueforkey eg: [userdefaults objectForKey:@"init_val"];